# Adding Ads via iAd and AdMob

Tags: trigger.io

I have a requirement to develop Android and iPhone versions of the same app, so I'm considering Trigger.io. My question is, I need to support ads on both versions of the application. I'm thinking on using iAd for the iPhone version, and AdMob for the Android one. Does Trigger.io support integration with these two systems? If true, is there any example I can use to start things up? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an existing integration with iAds or AdMob, but you should be able to get that done with our [native plugin system](https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/native_plugins/index.html)

We've published webinar recordings for [iOS](https://vimeo.com/62099282) and [Android](https://vimeo.com/66233891) to help get you started.

Comment: I think it is not possible, how are we going to return this -> `adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());` to our javascript since forgeTask only accepts String, jsonElement, etc.?

It would be a great help to us if you would be able to create an ads module.